Anexar arquivo .PDF ao enviar um email usando JavaMail
Estou usando o Javamail para envio de email, com anexo. Porém ao anexar um arquivo com extensão ".pdf" ele está atribuindo o conteúdo ao corpo do email, e não como arquivo anexado.
Já tentei diversas formas, porém sem sucesso.
Vi até nesse forúm Anexar arquivo TXT usando Javamail que a dúvida é a mesma, implementei o mesmo código que está lá, porém sem sucesso.
Segue trecho abaixo do código onde faço a atribuição do corpo em HTML e o anexo:
        // Parte do texto em HTML
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Texto
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlContent, "text/plain");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        //Anexo
        File file = new File(pathAnexoRelatorio.toUri());
        FileDataSource ds = new FileDataSource(file) {

            public String getContentType() {
                return "application/octet-stream";
            }
        };

        BodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
        mbp.setFileName(file.getName());
        mbp.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
        multipart.addBodyPart(mbp);

        message.setContent(multipart);```

O resultado que tenho sempre é esse no cliente de email:


------=_Part_0_1497650043.1719433823544 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit 
Corpo do email em HTML
------=_Part_0_1497650043.1719433823544 Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=report.pdf Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.pdf JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMiAwIG9iago8PC9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDI3NjI+ PnN0cmVhbQp4nJVay3LcNhbd6yu4mIVTlaEJkuBjye6mZLpaTZlka+HKpstSUpqyLY+syfzO/Nss 8gHzA4PHhSQCOGgyVUmqdC6uLg7OAXBBJRGL/s6iJOI1F//98u3inxeb6SIrIs7raLq7aKeLT+Jn 

O arquivo vem no corpo do email em base64 ao invés de vir como anexo


Já tentou mudar o "application/octet-stream" para "application/pdf", pode ser por isso que seu navegador nem seu provedor de email estão conseguindo montar o arquivo em anexo.

Já tentei mudar para application/pdf, porém sem sucesso, o resultado é o mesmo

Não duplique perguntas, siga as instruções fornecidas na pergunta original. Os comentários aqui serão bloqueados, se precisar comentar algo faça na postagem original: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/595569/3635
